# Difference between cryptanalysis and brute force attacks

Tags: cryptanalysis, brute-force-attack

I wonder about the difference between brute force and cryptanalysis attack?
as my professor asked us about the difference,
but i searched and found that the brute force is one type of cryptanalysis attacks is that true or there's a difference between them ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you searched and found something, so what's your doubt exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a matter of terminology, but generally cryptanalysis and brute force attack are mutually exclusive. *Cryptanalysis* means attacking a cryptographic system by looking for something clever that the designers of the system didn't think of, for example finding a mathematical relation that makes some computation fasters. A *brute force attack* is one that doesn't use any intelligence and enumerates all possibilities; cryptography is always vulnerable to brute force attacks, but if properly designed it makes them practically impossible by arranging for the probability of success to be utterly negligible.